# ServiceLoader in Android "Couldn't instantiate class"

Tags: java, android, serviceloader

I have a problem with integrate the `ServiceLoader` to my Android app, to integrate a plugin system.

```
public class StrategieClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

  private ClassLoader m_SystemClassLoader;

  private static Set<String> m_SaveClasses = new HashSet<String>();
  {
      m_SaveClasses.add( ESpielsteinFarbe.class.getName() );
      m_SaveClasses.add( ISpielstein.class.getName() );
      m_SaveClasses.add( SpielsteinPosition.class.getName() );

      m_SaveClasses.add( ISpielzug.class.getName() );
      m_SaveClasses.add( IStrategie.class.getName() );
      m_SaveClasses.add( IStrategieFactory.class.getName() );
      m_SaveClasses.add( StrategieException.class.getName() );
  }

  public StrategieClassLoader(URL[] p_Classpath, ClassLoader p_Parent) {
    super(p_Classpath, p_Parent);
    m_SystemClassLoader = getSystemClassLoader();
  }

  @Override
  protected synchronized Class<?> loadClass(String p_ClassName, boolean p_Resolve)
      throws ClassNotFoundException {

    Class<?> l_Class = findLoadedClass(p_ClassName);
    if (l_Class == null) {
      if (isSystemClass(p_ClassName)) {
        l_Class = super.loadClass(p_ClassName, p_Resolve);
      } else {
        try {
          l_Class = findClass(p_ClassName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          l_Class = super.loadClass(p_ClassName, p_Resolve);
        }
      }
    }
    if (p_Resolve) {
      resolveClass(l_Class);
    }
    return l_Class;
  }

  private boolean isSystemClass(String p_ClassName) {
    return ( m_SaveClasses.contains( p_ClassName ) || p_ClassName.startsWith("java.") || p_ClassName.startsWith("javax.") ||
           p_ClassName.startsWith("com.sun."));
  }

  @Override
  public URL getResource(String p_ResourceName) {
    URL l_ResourceUrl = findResource(p_ResourceName);
    if (l_ResourceUrl == null) {
      l_ResourceUrl = super.getResource(p_ResourceName);
    }
    return l_ResourceUrl;
  }

  @Override
  public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String p_ResourceName) throws IOException {
    Enumeration<URL> l_LocalUrls = findResources(p_ResourceName);
    Enumeration<URL> l_ParentUrls = null;
    if (getParent() != null) {
      l_ParentUrls = getParent().getResources(p_ResourceName);
    }
    final List<URL> l_Urls = new ArrayList<URL>();
    if (l_LocalUrls != null) {
      while (l_LocalUrls.hasMoreElements()) {
        l_Urls.add(l_LocalUrls.nextElement());
      }
    }
    if (l_ParentUrls != null) {
      while (l_ParentUrls.hasMoreElements()) {
        l_Urls.add(l_ParentUrls.nextElement());
      }
    }
    return new Enumeration<URL>() {
      Iterator<URL> l_UrlIterator = l_Urls.iterator();

      public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        return l_UrlIterator.hasNext();
      }

      public URL nextElement() {
        return l_UrlIterator.next();
      }
    };
  }

  @Override
  public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String p_ResourceName) {
    URL l_ResourceUrl = getResource(p_ResourceName);
    try {
      return l_ResourceUrl != null ? l_ResourceUrl.openStream() : null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return null;
  }
}

public static List<IStrategieFactory> load(String p_path)
{
    List<IStrategieFactory> l_Facs = new ArrayList<IStrategieFactory>();

    File l_PluginDir = new File(p_path);

    for( File dir: l_PluginDir.listFiles() )
    {
        if( dir.isDirectory() )
        {
            File[] l_Jars = dir.listFiles( new FilenameFilter() {

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File file, String name) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return name.endsWith( ".jar" );
                }
            });

            List<URL> l_Urls = new ArrayList<URL>();
            for( File jar: l_Jars )
            {
                try {
                    l_Urls.add( jar.toURI().toURL() );
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if( !l_Urls.isEmpty() )
            {
                StrategieClassLoader l_ClassLoader = new StrategieClassLoader(l_Urls.toArray( new URL[ l_Urls.size() ]), Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() );

                ServiceLoader<IStrategieFactory> loader = ServiceLoader.load(IStrategieFactory.class, l_ClassLoader);
                for( IStrategieFactory fac : loader )
                {
                    l_Facs.add( fac );
                }
            }
        }
    }   

    m_Factories = l_Facs;

    return m_Factories; 
    }   
}
```

The .jar Files copied from the assets folder on the externalStorage, the Class can access to all files but it's crashes after run

```
ServiceLoader<IStrategieFactory> loader = ServiceLoader.load(IStrategieFactory.class, l_ClassLoader);

13967-13967/dievierlustigen5.dhbw.de.a4wins E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: dievierlustigen5.dhbw.de.a4wins, PID: 13967
 java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: Couldn't instantiate class de.dhbw.fourwins.strategy.EasyStratFactory
     at java.util.ServiceLoader$ServiceIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:216)
     at dievierlustigen5.dhbw.de.a4wins.strategy.StrategyLoader.load(StrategyLoader.java:78)
     at dievierlustigen5.dhbw.de.a4wins.DifficultyActivity.onCreate(DifficultyActivity.java:43)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3208)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.net.URL.getProtocol()' on a null object reference
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.getPermissions(URLClassLoader.java:614)
     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.getPD(SecureClassLoader.java:140)
     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:93)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$600(URLClassLoader.java:55)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$URLJarHandler.createClass(URLClassLoader.java:364)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$URLJarHandler.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:303)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:748)
     at dievierlustigen5.dhbw.de.a4wins.strategy.StrategieClassLoader.loadClass(StrategieClassLoader.java:56)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
     at java.util.ServiceLoader$ServiceIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:214)
     at dievierlustigen5.dhbw.de.a4wins.strategy.StrategyLoader.load(StrategyLoader.java:78) 
     at dievierlustigen5.dhbw.de.a4wins.DifficultyActivity.onCreate(DifficultyActivity.java:43) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3208) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Maybe anyone know how to solve the Error?

Comment: I am skeptical that using `ServiceLoader` is a good plan on Android. That being said, [this developer got it working](http://francistoth.github.io/blog/jekyll/update/2015/07/10/coding-an-android-dynamic-class-loader.html).

Comment: Did you get permission in Manifest?

Comment: @ibtehaz which permission exactly ? Do you mean WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE yes both are set in the manifest, because without i couldn't copy the .jar's from the assetfolder to the external storage

Comment: @Emil the problem is i have no other choice we make an it project at university and have to use the service loader to load the strategies for connect four, the .jar files are all fine you testet die loader in eclipse and there are not problems to load the .jar files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no possible to load normal .class files during runtime with Android, because
Android use an other VM, which can only read .dex files.

So I have to use the DexClassLoader